# Problem booting to 15.04

Tags: 15.04

When I boot up I get this instead of a login screen:

```
starting version 291
[ OK ] Started ACPI event daemon.
                Starting ACPI event daemon...
```

...and it stays there. I'm not sure what's going on here. Can anyone help me?

My first boot after installation of 15.04 went off without a hitch. I noticed this happened when I shut down earlier, but I forced power off. Could that be the source of the problem?

If I go to tty1 and enter

```
startx
```

The desktop appears like normal. Is there a way to fix this? I'm currently trying to create another bootable USB stick to try installing the OS again.

I would simply reinstall the OS, but my flash drive won't start up and my windows machine won't recognize it. I'm stuck .

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue here. Could not even switch to terminal as the screen would constantly switch between the console with the ACPI output and the (immediately crashing) graphical login screen.

Solved this issue by :

- booting into recovery option from grub boot menu
- in the recovery menu, choosing dpkg option and saying "no" to make any changes. This is only to make the recovery remount the root partition in read/write mode.
- then choosing terminal option.

In the terminal:

- I checked if nvidia-drivers are installed:

  ```
  dpkg -l | grep nvidia
  ```

And to my surprise (the system is a laptop with integrated intel graphics) they were!!

- So I removed the nvidia drivers with:

  ```
  apt-get purge nvidia*
  ```

And rebooted the system.